# beginner C++ importing file, finding sum and average

Tags: c++, import, sum

I'm new to C++ and not sure where to start importing a txt file with 100 numbers, then to make a code to find the sum and average of up to 100 numbers
Can anybody help?

Comment: What about some code?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you already have given the answer yourself. First, find out how to read a file. Then, find out how to convert the text in the file to numbers (you will have to decide what kind of number, like integers, floats or complex). Then, summing up the numbers and computing the average are the next two steps.

Just take one step at a time and make sure you always only try small tasks that you can comprehend in isolation. Even when writing something bigger, it often pays to create a simple test example for one small task first. Also, creating a small test example is a prerequisite to posting at Stack Overflow, see the guidelines for further info.

Answer (score 0):

I hope, this example will help you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

/* file.txt
2
3
4
6
*/


int main()
{
    string line;
    ifstream file("file.txt"); // reading from file: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        int sum = 0;
        while (getline(file, line))
        {
            int num = atoi(line.c_str()); // convertion from string into int with 'atoi': http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/
            sum += num;
        }
        file.close();

        cout << "Sum is " << sum << endl; // Sum is 15
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks,Is my file meant to open? I dont understand how to find the sum of the numbers in my text file